# Организация React-компонентов с React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, jsx, react-router-dom

Есть вот такой интерфейс:

[image: EmployerList]

и есть 3 компонента: `PageEmployerList`, `EmployerListContainer` и `EmployerList`.

Не совсем понятны *границы* компонентов.

В каком из этих компонентов должны находится заголовок страницы и кнопки «Список сотрудников» и «Новый сотрудник» ?

Answer (score 0):

Если я вас правильно понимаю, то вы не хотите, чтобы в презентационную компоненту была предоставлена бизнес-логика. В таком случае, я действительно не создаю ее там, но возвращаю ее как return в компоненте-контейнере, в которой как раз-таки эта логика(где и есть надлежащие функции и данные есть) там и присутствует. И отрисовываю через Route как раз-таки этот контейнер. Так получается более чистый код.

Comment: Данил, я отредактировал текст, вопрос больше о том, где какие элементы расположить.